# Declaring encoding in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to split a string in python using this code:

```
means="a ، b ، c"
lst=means.split("،")
```

but I get this error message:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file dict.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

How do I declare an encoding?

Answer (score 71):

Put:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

as the first line of the file (or second line if using *nix) and save the file as UTF-8.

If you're using Python 2, use Unicode string literals (`u"..."`), for example:

```
means = u"a ، b ، c"
lst = means.split(u"،")
```

If you're using Python 3, string literals are Unicode already (unless marked as bytestrings `b"..."`).

Comment: @imrek then instead of declaring an encoding of UTF-8, declare the encoding that your file actually uses. It has nothing to do with the Python version and everything to do with the file itself.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare an encoding for your file, as documented [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/encodings.html).