# Python: Can't write to file - UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

This code should write some text to file.
When I'm trying to write my text to console, everything works. But when I try to write the text into the file, I get UnicodeEncodeError. I know, that this is a common problem which can be solved using proper decode or encode, but I tried it and still getting the same UnicodeEncodeError. What am I doing wrong?

I've attached an example.

```
print "(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)".decode("utf-8")%(dict.get('name'),dict.get('description'),dict.get('ico'),dict.get('city'),dict.get('ulCislo'),dict.get('psc'),dict.get('weby'),dict.get('telefony'),dict.get('mobily'),dict.get('faxy'),dict.get('emaily'),dict.get('dic'),dict.get('ic_dph'),dict.get('kategorie')[0],dict.get('kategorie')[1],dict.get('kategorie')[2])
```

> > > (StarBuy s.r.o.,Inzertujte s foto, auto-moto, oblečenie, reality, prácu, zvieratá, starožitnosti, dovolenky, nábytok, všetko pre deti, obuv, stroj....

```
with open("test.txt","wb") as f:
   f.write("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)".decode("utf-8")%(dict.get('name'),dict.get('description'),dict.get('ico'),dict.get('city'),dict.get('ulCislo'),dict.get('psc'),dict.get('weby'),dict.get('telefony'),dict.get('mobily'),dict.get('faxy'),dict.get('emaily'),dict.get('dic'),dict.get('ic_dph'),dict.get('kategorie')[0],dict.get('kategorie')[1],dict.get('kategorie')[2]))
```

> > > UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u010d' in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)

Where could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Unicode Encode Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error)

Comment: why are you decoding it?

Comment: unrelated: you could simplify the string formatting: `u"({})".format(','.join(map(your_dict.get, ['name', 'description', 'ico', ..., ic_dph'])+your_dict['kategorie'][:3]))`

Answer (score 5):

To write Unicode text to a file, you could use [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from io import open

with open('utf8.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(u'\u010d')
```

It is default on Python 3.

Note: you should not use the binary file mode (`'b'`) if you want to write text.

`# coding: utf8` that defines the *source code* encoding has nothing to do with it.

If you see `sys.setdefaultencoding()` outside of `site.py` or Python tests; assume the code is broken.

Answer (score 1):

@ned-batchelder is right. You have to declare that the system default encoding is "utf-8". The coding comment `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` doesn't do this.

To declare the system default encoding, you have to import the module `sys`, and call `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`. However, `sys` was previously imported by the system and its `setdefaultencoding` method was removed. So you have to reload it before you call the method.

So, you will need to add the following codes at the beginning:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly declare that python use UTF-8 encoding.

The answer to this SO question explains how to do that: [Declaring Encoding in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238307/declaring-encoding-in-python)

Comment: I have it already declared: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on the top of my code

Comment: The coding comment on the .py file only affects how the .py source is decoded.  It has nothing to do with the way data is decoded.

Comment: Then maybe you should ensure the strings in the dict are UTF-8 encoded it before trying to decode them as such. 

You've only shown us a line of code - which isn't enough for me or probably anyone else to work with if it's a semantic issue.

Comment: Do you want to write a unicode string or ASCII string to the file?

To write a unicode string, you probably should replace `decode('utf-8')` with `encode('utf-8')`. 

But I'm assuming the strings you are retrieving from the Dict are ASCII encoded.

If that is the case, then you don't need the `.decode('utf-8')` at all.

Comment: @SW_user2953243 I'm getting data from web page which has "utf-8" in head. I want to write these data into the file. And it says that 'ordinal not in range(128)'

Comment: You probably need to parse the the header until you get to the actual UTF-8 payload. Then pass the payload to Stream.Parse(). I don't think the header is UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2:

1. Declare document encoding on top of the file (if not done yet):

   `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
2. Replace `.decode` with `.encode`:

   ```
   with open("test.txt","wb") as f:
       f.write("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)".encode("utf-8")%(dict.get('name'),dict.get('description'),dict.get('ico'),dict.get('city'),dict.get('ulCislo'),dict.get('psc'),dict.get('weby'),dict.get('telefony'),dict.get('mobily'),dict.get('faxy'),dict.get('emaily'),dict.get('dic'),dict.get('ic_dph'),dict.get('kategorie')[0],dict.get('kategorie')[1],dict.get('kategorie')[2]))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have the right story, but as far as I can tell not the right solution. You need to set the encoding for the file object:

```py
with open("test.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(stuff)
```